# What restrictions does transport security with Windows authentication require?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I'm investigating using a WSHttpBinding in WCF with transport security and Windows authentication.  However I'm having problems finding information on what restrictions using this applies to the server and client, i.e. domain membership of the machines or users and any restrictions that might apply in other areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Windows Authentication then your service will authenticate against a single domain and it is fairly simple to setup.  I believe you can setup a trust with other domains to allow them to windows authenticate as well but then you are opening up a door into a whole other level of complexity and/or security concerns.

Without knowning more about what the purpose of this service or how many domains (and how they are configured for access). I would probably consider using UserName Authentication which is also fairly simple to setup. This is a good [link](http://codebetter.com/blogs/peter.van.ooijen/archive/2010/03/22/a-simple-wcf-service-with-username-password-authentication-the-things-they-don-t-tell-you.aspx) to get started on Custom Authentication.